# How to mock useRef value change after click event in react native with jest and react native testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I have a component named MyComponent and it calls 2 APIs when it mounts. 1st API shows the initial data and when I click a particular button, it shows data from 2nd API. I have used useRef to decide which data to show.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const random = React.useRef(false);
  
  const { data, isFetching, isError } = useMakeFirstAPICall();
  const { data: a, isFetching: b, isError: c, refetch: d } = useMakeSecondAPICall();

  const usedData = random.current ? a : data;
  const usedIsFetching = random.current ? b : isFetching;
  const usedIsError = random.current ? c : isError;

  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable
        testID="my.btn"
        onPress={() => {
          random.current = true;
          d();
        }}
      >
        <MyCustomIcon />
      </Pressable>
      {!usedIsFetching && <ShowData data={usedData} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I was testing the data changes after the button click. I have managed to mock api calls. But after button click the data is not changing. I tried to mock the useRef value but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my test code.

```
jest.mock("src/api1", () => ({
  useMakeFirstAPICall: () => ({
    data: MockData1,
  }),
}));

jest.mock("src/api2", () => ({
  useMakeSecondAPICall: () => ({
    data: MockData2,
  }),
}));

describe("Testing MyComponent", () => {
  test("Test button press action", async () => {

    const reference = { current: true };
    Object.defineProperty(reference, "current", {
      get: jest.fn(() => null),
      set: jest.fn(() => null),
    });
    jest.spyOn(React, "useRef").mockReturnValueOnce(reference);

    render(<MyComponent />);

    const gridList1 = await screen.findAllByTestId("grid.card");
    expect(gridList1).toBeTruthy();
    expect(gridList1.length).toBe(5);

    const myButton = await screen.findByTestId("my.btn");
    await fireEvent(myButton, "click");

    const gridList2 = await waitFor(() => screen.findAllByTestId("grid.card"));
    expect(gridList2).toBeTruthy();
    expect(gridList2.length).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

This is the error it's giving me.

[image]

Comment: Did you check that your component was properly re-rendered? (using a console.log for instance).
Also you are mocking `React.useRef` to late, if you want to mock it, you need to do it before `render`, at least.

Comment: I changed my code as you suggested and tried to screen.debug() but the screen is not rerendering. It's showing the initial MockData1 with 5 elements.